# Homology and intrinsic dimension

Tags: homology-cohomology

I was wondering can homology give us any tool for understanding the intrinsic dimension of high-dimensional (scattered) data?
If yes, available software for that kind of analysis is also appreciated.

Comment: Persistent homology? Use the persistent homology packages for R.

Comment: @Chickenmancer I am new on that topic and got interested in discussing with a helpful mathematician guy and forgot to ask about intrinsic dimension. I have read some introductory material, and mostly they have tried to explain how to find holes and clusters, ... Any recommendation for dimensionality analysis is appreciated.

Comment: You may want to try this paper. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.00179.pdf